# inner object search elasticsearch v2.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents like below in elasticsearch:

```
{ 
  "region": "US",
  "manager": { 
    "age":     30,
    "name": { 
      "first": "John",
      "last":  "Smith"
    }
  }
}
```

As per [this page in documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-object-type.html), inner objects can be search without providing full path as well. Example, I can say show me docs with `first = John`.

This was working for me in verson 1.5.2 *out-of-the-box* but I recently migrated to version 2.3.2 of elastic and this *non-fully-qualified-name-based-search* has stopped working. Now I have to explicitly say `name.first = John` which I don't want to do because of dynamic nature of keys in docs.

I have tried explicitly saying that name is an object type while declaring mappings. And also by including name in all using `include_in_all` option as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html).

Does anyone know how to get it working in version 2.3.2 of elasticsearch. How do I search inner fields in elastic by just saying `first=John` and not `name.first=John`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature (short name) has been removed for elasticsearch 2.x.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html

This is related to ensuring that conflicted mapping's cannot be created, and to reduce ambiguity.